# How to have keys in my Json, not only values

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, rest, primevue

I created a datatable from primevue, but I only get empty rows.

I looked where it could come from and I think it comes from my Json, whose fields have no key. What corrections should be made so that this Json becomes standard again and my data can be displayed? Thanks in advance.

**A short exemple of the Json I get:**

```
[
   [
    32,
    "DE BELLOUET Jag",
    "1.3.13.3.",
    "Cid polseruti sau"
   ],
   [
    15,
    "NOURAUD Benjamin",
    "1.3.13.3.",
    "Cid polseruti sau"
   ]
]
```

**A short exemple of the jSon I need:**

```
[
   [
    "id":32,
    "fullName":"DE BELLOUET Jag",
    "acs":"1.3.13.3.",
    "nom_service":"Cid polseruti sau"
   ],
   [
    "id":15,
    "fullName":"NOURAUD Benjamin",
    "acs":"1.3.13.3.",
    "nom_service":"Cid polseruti sau"
   ]
]
```

**The main program: gererPersonnes.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="principal_personnes">
        <div class="bandeau">
            <div>{{titre}}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Liste des agents actifs</h2>
            <DataTable :value="agents" :paginator="true" :rows="10" class="tableau">
                 <template #empty>
                    Pas d'agent trouvé.
                </template>
                <Column field="id" :sortable="true" header="Id" headerStyle="width: 3em" bodyStyle="text-align: center"></Column>
                <Column field="fullName" :sortable="true" header="Nom - Prénom" headerStyle="width: 250px"></Column>
                <Column field="service.acs" :sortable="true" header="A.C.S." headerStyle="width: 150px"></Column>
                <Column field="service.nom_service" :sortable="true" header="Service" headerStyle="width: 250px; text-aling: left;"></Column>
                <Column headerStyle="width: 8em">
                    <template #body >
                        <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-user" class="p-button-text" title="Détails"></Button>
                        <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-text" title="Modifier"></Button>
                        <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-text" title="Supprimer"></Button>
                    </template>
                </Column>
            </DataTable>
        </div>
        <div class="button_gerer">
            <button type="submit" class="boutton coin_vert" @click="cAjouter()">Ajouter un agent</button>
            <button type="button" class="boutton coin_rouge" @click="cQuitter()">Abandon</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
:root {
    --gaucheP: 660px;
}

.principal_personnes {
    height: var(--haut);
    width: var(--large);
    background-color:cornsilk;
}

.tableau {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.pi-user {
    color:blue;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.pi-pencil {
    color:green;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.pi-trash {
    color:red;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    padding: 0rem 0rem;
}

h2 {
    text-align:center;
}

.button_gerer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 30px / 130px 130px;
    column-gap: 220px;  /* Firefox 63+ Chrome 84+ */
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    padding-left: var(--gaucheP);
    padding-top: 40px;
}

</style>

<script>
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable';
import Column from 'primevue/column';
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import ('primeicons/primeicons.css');

import AgentService from '../../services/AgentService'

export default {
    name: 'gererPersonnes',
    beforeCreate() {
        window.self.document.title = "gererPersonnes"; // modification du titre de l'onglet
        document.getElementById('menuU').style.setProperty('display', 'none'); //menu non affiché
    },
    components : {
        DataTable,
        Column,
        Button
    },
    data() {
        return {
            agents : null,
            titre: 'Gérer les personnes',
        }
    },
    methods : {
        cQuitter() {
            let a = confirm("Voulez quitter la gestion des personnes ?");
            if (a == true) {
                this.$router.push("/");
            }
        },
        cAjouter() {
            let routeUrl = this.$router.resolve({
                path : "/agents/add_agent",
            });
            window.open(routeUrl.href, '_blank');
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.AgentService = new AgentService;
    },
    mounted () {
        this.AgentService.getAgentServices().then(data => this.agents = data);
    },
    AgentService : null

}


//Centrage du formulaire de la page
var inHeight = window.innerHeight - 140;
var inWidth = window.innerWidth;

if (inWidth > 1680) {
    inWidth = 1680;
}

var l = Math.floor((inWidth - 460 - 20)/2);
var padLeft = l + 'px';
var hauteur = inHeight + 'px';

var r = document.querySelector(':root');
r.style.setProperty('--gaucheP', padLeft);
r.style.setProperty('--haut', hauteur);

</script>
```

**The service called by gererPersonnes.vue : AgentService.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const URL = "/cote-s-rest/rest/agent"; 
const URL2 = "/cote-s-rest/rest/password/"; 
const URL3 = "/cote-s-rest/rest/agent/patronyme"; 
const URL4 = "/cote-s-rest/rest/agent/agentServ";

export default class AgentService {

insertAgent(agent) {
    return axios.post(URL, agent).then(resp => {
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    });
}

passNewAgent(agent) {
    return axios.post(URL2, agent).then(resp => {
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    });
}

getAgents() {
    return axios.get(URL3).then(resp => {
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    });
}

getAgentServices() {
    return axios.get(URL4).then(resp => {
        return Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    });
}

}
```

**The class AgentServ use in Java**

```
    
package fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.dao.agent;

/**
 * Classe de requete pour la liste "AgentServ"
 * 
 * @author Jean Paul Vandekerkhove
 * @version 0.0.2.SNAPSHOT
 */
public class AgentServ {

    //------------------------
    // Attributs
    //------------------------
    private long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String acs;
    private String nom_service;
        
    //------------------------
    // Constructeurs
    //------------------------
    
    /**
     * Constructeur vide
     */
    public AgentServ() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructeur complet
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param fullName
     * @param acs
     * @param nom_service
     */
    public AgentServ(long id, String fullName, String acs, String nom_service) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.acs = acs;
        this.nom_service = nom_service;
    }

    //------------------------
    // Getters et Setters
    //------------------------
    /**
     * Retourne l'identifiant de l'Agent
     * @return id - identifiant de l'Agent
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    /**
     * MaJ de l'Identifiant de l'Agent
     * @param id - Identifiant de l'agent
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retourne l'identité complete de l'Agent
     * @return fullName - nom-prénom de l'Agent
     */
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    
    /**
     * MaJ de l'identité complete de l'Agent
     * @param fullName - nom-prénom de l'Agent
     */
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retourne l'acs du service de l'Agent
     * @return acs - acs du service de l'Agent
     */
    public String getAcs() {
        return acs;
    }
    
    /**
     * MaJ de l'acs du service de l'Agent
     * @param acs - acs du service de l'Agent
     */
    public void setAcs(String acs) {
        this.acs = acs;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retourne le libellé du service de l'Agent
     * @return nom_service - libellé du service de l'Agent
     */
    public String getNom_service() {
        return nom_service;
    }
    
    /**
     * MaJ le libellé du service de l'Agent
     * @param nom_service - libellé du service de l'Agent
     */
    public void setNom_service(String nom_service) {
        this.nom_service = nom_service;
    }

}
```

**The List Method use in AgentDaoImpl.java**

```
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<AgentServ> listAgentService() {
        String buf = null;
        buf = "SELECT a.id AS id,(btrim(a.nom) || ' ' || btrim(a.prenom)) AS fullName, s.acs AS acs, s.libelle AS nom_service ";
        buf += "FROM Agent a INNER JOIN Service s ON a.service = s ";
        buf += "WHERE ((a.actif = true) OR ((a.actif = false) AND (a.dateSuppression >= CURRENT_DATE)))";

        List<AgentServ> agents= em.createQuery(buf.toString()).getResultList();

        return agents;
    }
```

**The REST method**

```
package fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.rest.agent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.validation.ValidationException;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.dao.agent.Agent;
import fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.dao.agent.AgentDAO;
import fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.dao.agent.AgentServ;
import fr.gouv.finances.douane.cotes.dao.agent.ListAgent;
/**
 * Classe de ressources REST de la classe ejb Agent
 *
 * @author VANDEKERKHOVE
 * @version 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
 */
@Path("/agent")
@RequestScoped
public class AgentResourceRESTService {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private Validator validator;

    @Inject
    private AgentDAO repository;

    @GET
    @Path("/agentServ")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public List<AgentServ> ListAgentService() {
        return (List<AgentServ>) repository.listAgentService();
    }
```

**The pom of the rest project**

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>fr.gouv.finances.douane.cote-s</groupId>
    <artifactId>cote-s</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  
  <artifactId>cote-s-rest</artifactId>
  <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <description>Modules Rest de Cote-S</description>
  
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.gouv.finances.douane.cote-s</groupId>
            <artifactId>cote-s-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
    
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
    
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2.Final</version> <!-- $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->   
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
                  
         <!-- Tests -->
       
         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
       
    </dependencies>  

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
      
</project>
```

Comment: The example and the desired result you give is not an JSON but a array containing other arrays.

Comment: Thank's. I added the pom of rest project. May be something wrong or forgetted.

Answer (score 0):

The *Json you need* is actually not json. here is what you actually want :

```json
[
   {
    "id":32,
    "fullName":"DE BELLOUET Jag",
    "acs":"1.3.13.3.",
    "nom_service":"Cid polseruti sau"
   },
   {
    "id":15,
    "fullName":"NOURAUD Benjamin",
    "acs":"1.3.13.3.",
    "nom_service":"Cid polseruti sau"
   }
]
```

the important detail is the `{` and `}` characters that are used to denoted an Object or a map of properties.

With that said you should probably create a POJO to store the result of your SQL request. maybe something like :

```java
public class Agent {
    private Integer id;
    private String fullName;
    private String acs;
    private String nomService;

    // add some getters and setter here

}
```

Maybe returning a `List<Agent>` from your rest method could be enough. If not you could take a look at the [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) library to serialize a `List<Agent>` into json.

Comment: Thank for your help. Problem, the "json" is always the same as the first exemple. New codes are online. I hope to finally be right. I've been looking for three months, I've tried so many things that nervous breakdown threatens

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the solution actually involves creating a class (AgentServ).

But hibernate doesn't like my request, and it had to have the results in a list of Object[].

Then we had to cast the previous results, Include the lines in an agent object one step at a time and then add it to the  list.

The datatable now returns the requested result.

Below is the final code.

```
public List<AgentServ> listAgentService() {
    String buf = null;
    buf = "SELECT a.id AS id,(btrim(a.nom) || ' ' || btrim(a.prenom)) AS fullName, s.acs AS acs, s.libelle AS nom_service ";
    buf += "FROM Agent a INNER JOIN Service s ON a.service = s ";
    buf += "WHERE ((a.actif = true) OR ((a.actif = false) AND (a.dateSuppression >= CURRENT_DATE)))";

    List<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(buf.toString(), Object[].class).getResultList();
    List<AgentServ> agents = new ArrayList<AgentServ>();
    
    for(Object[] row : query) {
        AgentServ agent = new AgentServ();
        agent.setId((long) row[0]);
        agent.setFullName((String) row[1]);
        agent.setAcs((String) row[2]);
        agent.setNom_service((String) row[3]);
        
        agents.add(agent);
    }
    
    return agents;      
}
```